# map.setView is not a function in Vue 2

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, leaflet, vuetify.js

I am making a leaflet map with geolocation that worked on vue2. Now when I use my code for setView on the leaflet I get the error

```
"this.map.setView is not a function
TypeError: this.map.setView is not a function
    at eval (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js??clonedRuleSet-40.use[0]!./node_modules/@vue/vue-loader-v15/lib/index.js??vue-loader-options!./src/components/mapLeafletVue.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js:44:20)"
```

My Dependencies:

```
"dependencies": {
    "core-js": "^3.8.3",
    "leaflet": "^1.9.4",
    "vue": "^2.6.14",
    "vue2-leaflet": "^2.7.1",
    "vuetify": "^2.6.0"
  },
```

My Codes:

```
<template>
  <v-app>
  
    <v-main>
      <!-- <v-btn color="blue" @click="getlocation()" class="ma-9">get location</v-btn> -->
      <v-card class="ma-10 d-flex flex-column align-center pa-5">
        <v-card-title primary-title>
          your location
        </v-card-title>
        
      <v-card-text>
         <p>lat: {{lat}} <span class="ml-4">lng: {{lng}}</span> </p>
      </v-card-text> 
        <div class="mx-9">
          <div id="mapContainer" style="width:300px;height:300px"></div>
        </div>
      </v-card>
      
    </v-main>
  </v-app>
</template>

<script>

import L from 'leaflet'
export default {
  name: 'App',

  data: () => ({
      lat :0,
      lng :0,
      map:'',
      mapContainer:''
  }),
  mounted(){
    this.getlocation()
    this.map = L.map('mapContainer').setView([51.505, -0.09], 13);
    L.tileLayer('https://tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
    maxZoom: 17,
    attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a>'
}).addTo(this.map);
  },

    methods:{
      getlocation(){
       if( navigator.geolocation){
       navigator.geolocation.watchPosition((position)=>{
        this.lat= position.coords.latitude
        this.lng= position.coords.longitude
        this.map.setView([this.lat , this.lng],14)

  L.marker([this.lat,this.lng]).addTo(this.map)
        .bindPopup(`<b>this is your location.</b><br>${this.lat} | ${this.lng}`)
        
    })
       }
    }
  },
};
</script>
```

Comment: If you've upgraded, consult the latest version of the [documentation](https://vue2-leaflet.netlify.app/quickstart/#accessing-leaflet-api).  You will need to change how you access the map object.  Including needing to use [nextTick](https://vue2-leaflet.netlify.app/faq/#how-can-i-access-the-leaflet-map-object) if accessing the map in the mounted hook.